# Loading External Python Library from Within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, libraries, jupyter

I'm trying to load an external Python library called "[visa](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)" into my Jupyter notebook running on Windows 7. This library allows real-world data capture from lab equipment to be captured for analysis in Python.

When I do the following I do not see this visa library present - I expect this since I do not know how to import a library that is not already present in my Jupyter notebook enviornment.

```
!pip list
```

How do I specify a path in the Windows 7 file system to run this command from within the Jupyter notebook to add the visa library to Jypyter so I can then do an "import visa" in the notebook?

```
!pip "install path to visa library in Windows 7 file system"
```

I expect to be able to load libraries in Jupyter and make it extensible just like I can load libraries into Python running from the command line.

The result of `!pip install` is:

```
Collecting visa
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement visa (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for visa
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running within Jupyter? (You can do `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` to find out)

Comment: use pip install pyvisa . You also need visa32.dll from national instruments (downloadable) to acually use visa to control your instruments.

Comment: Here's the output from sys.version.info

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: and the !pip install pyvisa command looks like it worked. I'll go look for the visa32.dll from national instruments but I'm actually trying to control Keysight PXI equipment

Comment: Here's the output from the pyvisa input:

Comment: output:  Successfully built pyvisa
Installing collected packages: pyvisa
Successfully installed pyvisa-1.8

Comment: Glad it worked. Keysight has their version of visa. either one should work.